# PHP Mysql Json and Arabic language

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have been inserting Arabic language data in mysql using php and an html form. After inserting data into mysql table the data looks like this Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù… However when i select this data onto my web page it shows perfect arabic sentence. However when i expose this data to json_encode function and try to read this data from android, the android shows Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù… after parsing json. Is there any way to represent this data in android meaningfully.

Update:

```
http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

i am also using  this meta tag in my show page. Without this meta tag my browser also shows data as like this Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…

Thanks

Comment: You say you are trying to view the data within MySQL.  How?  mysql through a terminal?  If so, please try setting the terminal encoding as I said in my answer.

Comment: i am using http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" as meta tag

Comment: h_a86, yes, that meta tag works for viewing through your browser.  But in yout question you say that it's not appearing correctly in MySQL.  I'm a bit confused now as to what you're actually trying to fix.... the browser or a terminal that's got a commandline connection to the mysql database?

Comment: After using meta tag the browser shows the data perfectly. the only problem is i am also exposing this data to a json web service using simple php function json encode.

Answer (score 1):

How are you viewing it through MySQL?  Putty?  Make sure you have your terminal encoding set to UTF-8 and not ASCII.

EDIT:  After trying this, I had to set my Putty encoding to **Win1256** for the characters to appear correctly in the console.

**Putty settings:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same character encoding over all platforms. Ideally, use UTF-8.