# PHP MYSQL Insert Data in Arabic Language

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

I am trying to insert some Arabic Language data into MySQL using PHP and an HTML form. When I insert the data in to MYSQL table, the table field represents data as `Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…`.

But when I access the same data with PHP and show it in my webpage, it shows the correct data. I am using:

```
http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

`meta` tag in my web page to show Arabic data. My question is why my data looks like this: `Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…` in MySQL table, and how should I correct it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Mysql Json and Arabic language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262561/php-mysql-json-and-arabic-language)

Comment: I have found this article to be helpful: http://www.bluebox.net/news/2009/07/mysql_encoding/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to do both of the following:

1. Make sure your database encoding and collation is `utf8_general_ci` (both for the field itself and the table as well as the database).
2. Send two commands right after establishing a connection to the database:

   ```
   mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

   mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't mentioning the MySQL version that you are using, but if using 5.0.7 or later, as per the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php):

> This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysql_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended. See the MySQL character set concepts section for more information.

**e.g.,** <sup>Assuming that you are using the mysql_query extension.</sup>

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1',TRUE);

  mysql_selectdb('db1', $link);

  mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link); 
?>
```

**Other considerations:**

- The files being used should be encoded with UTF-8
- The database, table and field should all be encoded and using the collation `utf8_general_ci`
- The PHP headers and HTML headers should also be set to UTF-8

---

As a side note, The use of [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this line:

```
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
```

See this function:

```
function _connect($user, $pass, $host)
{
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

    if (!$conn)
        return false;

    @mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
    //more....
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Your database should be `utf8` supported. Try with `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```php
@mysql_query("set global character_set_results=utf8");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

try to change server and db and table collation

for example

ALTER DATABASE "DBNAME" CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - are you sure this is only a problem on the database side?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

`mysqli_set_charset($this->connect,'utf8');
 mysqli_query($this->connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 mysqli_query($this->connect, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`

Moreover, your table must be (utf8_general_ci) in the structure field.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please add some explanation to your content,[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Now PHP and MYSQL support any language. Use this function in database connectivity .

```
$this->links = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD);  
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', 
  character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', 
  character_set_server = 'utf8'", $this->links);
```

MYSQL database table field should be Collation=utf8_general_ci