# send and retrive arabic data from mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, utf-8, arabic

I want to bring Arabic data from mysql database I wrote the php code but it gives me ????? on arabic data any help to make it wokrs ??

```
<?php header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8'); 
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arabicd");
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($link))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'");
mysql_query("character_set_client = 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("character_set_connection = 'utf8'");  
mysql_query("character_set_database = 'utf8'");
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT question,answer FROM ask ");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));

if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. Stick with mysqli for everything.

Comment: I did still not working :\

Comment: Please post error details..

Comment: Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\wamp\www\ArabicCon.php on line 3
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\ArabicCon.php on line 9( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\ArabicCon.php on line 10
 Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\ArabicCon.php on line 11
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\ArabicCon.php on line 12
[{"0":"????","question":"????","1":"????","answer":"????"}]

Comment: @ArshidKV this is the errors appear !

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MYSQL Insert Data in Arabic Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262965/php-mysql-insert-data-in-arabic-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Though you can just use `set names utf8` instead of all that creepy queries, there is nothing here wrong about Arabic, cheers :)
- You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` which is not allowed
- Even if it's allowed to use `mysql` & `mysqli` connections interchangeably, you are passing parameters to`query` functions in an order that is different from expected
- You should exit the script in case of connection failure (or do what ever, just change the execution flow)
- That line `print(json_encode($output));` is error prone, what if there are no results came from the table ? the loop will never be entered and `$output` will not be defined, so you must initialize `$output` with empty array, it's also a good practice to check if the result set is empty and handle it in a separate block
- Also, it's preferred to enclose table names and columns in back ticks (`` ` ``) in case that a column has a name of a reserved keyword

Here is a working version of your code after fixing errors

```html
<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php 



$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if ($link === false)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
mysql_select_db("arabicd", $link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `ask`.`question`,`ask`.`answer` FROM `ask` ", $link);
$output = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

if(isset($data))
{
 echo $data;
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your notes it really helpful but still got same problem with arabic letters :\

Comment: make sure that the table 'ask' collation is 'utf8_general_ci'

Comment: no still not working it gives me the following  Array[{"0":"\u0633\u0624\u0627\u0644","question":"\u0633\u0624\u0627\u0644","1":"\u062c\u0648\u0627\u0628","answer":"\u062c\u0648\u0627\u0628"}]

Comment: yeah that's because you are using "json_encode", try "print_r" instead

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\ArabicCon.php on line 30
 :\

Comment: print_r($output) not print(print_r($output))

Comment: [{"0":"\u0633\u0624\u0627\u0644","question":"\u0633\u0624\u0627\u0644","1":"\u062c\u0648\u0627\u0628","answer":"\u062c\u0648\u0627\u0628"}] im sorry but still not working

Comment: print_r($output) 
not print(print_r($output)) 
not print_r(json_encode($output))

Comment: thank u its working now mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");
this line was missing

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in your PHP:

```
$db= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','225352','project');

$SQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';

mysqli_query($db,**$SQL**);) 
or die ( mysqli_error($SQL) );
```

Answer (score 1):

No, don't use the `mysql` interface, use `mysqli`.
No, don't use `SET NAMES`, use `mysqli_set_charset`.

Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; you will probably find that the column you are trying to write into is `CHARACTER SET latin`.  It needs to be utf8.

Text like `\u0633` implies that you need to add `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as the second argument to `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

just use this in your  tag in HTML page....

```
 meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

use < before meta word

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79114/discussion-on-answer-by-nouman-tahir-send-and-retrive-arabic-data-from-mysql-dat).